Insert PrimeNG Checkbox Custom Icon TemplateRef globally (via Directive?) [PrimeNG]
PrimeNG changed the icon mechanics of the ui components, I am updating Angular for that as well from 15 to 17. I want my custom Checkbox Icon.
Touching the html or the logic in the ts file where the p-checkbox is used, is not an option, but maybe using a directive instead.
I want to insert the icon template of the checkbox via directive
I am trying something like this
<p-checkbox checkboxIcon>
  <!-- this is not an OPTION
    <ng-template pTemplate="icon">
      <custom-icon></custom-icon>
    </ng-template>
  -->
</p-checkbox>

I somehow want to create the TemplateRef in the directive and insert it.
@Directive({
  selector: '[checkboxIcon]',
})
export class IconDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    @Self() private checkbox: Checkbox
  ) {}

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onModelChange(event): void {
    this.appendIconTemplate();
  }

  appendIconTemplate(): void {
    const iconTemplate = document.createElement('ng-template');
    iconTemplate.setAttribute('pTemplate', 'icon');
    iconTemplate.innerHTML = '<custom-icon></custom-icon>';
    this.element.nativeElement.appendChild(iconTemplate);
  }
}

I have a minimal reproduction of the issue here
Found something with @Self() and ComponentFactoryResolver. But never worked with that, can anyone help?
I think those questions here and here want to achieve something similar.

So, there's a few things to consider for your needs, firstly, there is no easy and clean way to add a child component using directives, we can use the TemplateRef and ViewContainerRef but the component will be added as a sibling.
We also can't make use of the HostListener in our case, as this will not have the expected behaviour when using it on a structural directive.
So we must take a different approach, as the StackBlitz you shared is in Angular 17, I've made use of signals.
First, we need a new Component to encapsulate the custom icon.
@Component({
  selector: 'appCustomIcon',
  template: `
    <custom-icon></custom-icon>
  `,
})
export class CustomIconContainer {}

Then we can modify the directive to be able to create our CustomIconContainer inside of its embedded view :
@Directive({
  selector: '[checkboxIcon]',
})
export class IconDirective {
  // We will now us an input to know if the icon must be shown
  checkboxIcon = input<boolean>(false);

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    // This effect will listen on the changes in our input.
    effect(() => {
      // Using the signal will mark it to be used by the effect.
      const showIcon = this.checkboxIcon();

      // We run the rest of the logic in the untracked function to avoid
      // side effects
      untracked(() => {
        if (showIcon) this.appendIconTemplate();
        else this.resetView();
      });
    });
  }

  appendIconTemplate(): void {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    const embeddedView = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
      this.templateRef
    );
    const component = this.viewContainer.createComponent(CustomIconContainer);

    // This is the "hack" that allows us to create the component
    // as a child of the element
    embeddedView.rootNodes[0].appendChild(component.location.nativeElement);
  }

  resetView(): void {
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }
}

To avoid having to rely on a HostListener, we will instead listen on clicks on the checkbox itself, here's the new ChboxDemo class :
export class ChboxDemo {
  protected showCustomIcon = false;
  // The checked boolean is used to keep the state of the checkbox
  // between the view container refreshes
  protected checked = false;

  protected onClick() {
    this.showCustomIcon = !this.showCustomIcon;
  }
}

<div class="card">
  <p-checkbox
    binary="true"
    label="label"

    (click)="onClick()"
    *checkboxIcon="showCustomIcon"
    [(ngModel)]="checked"
  >
  </p-checkbox>
</div>

There was a last small problem where the icon would not show, to fix it, I simpled added a width to the svg element :
<svg style="width: 20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path
    d="M14.83,12,18,8.82A1,1,0,0,0,18,7.4L16.6,6a1,1,0,0,0-1.42,0L12,9.17,8.82,6A1,1,0,0,0,7.4,6L6,7.4A1,1,0,0,0,6,8.82L9.17,12,6,15.18A1,1,0,0,0,6,16.6L7.4,18a1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0L12,14.83,15.18,18a1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0L18,16.6a1,1,0,0,0,0-1.42Z"
  />
</svg>

Here's your forked StackBlitz with the working solution :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/btpn8a-as1ppw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fchbox-demo.html
I hope this helps and I'm available for any further questions.

TY so much for your help! Though I cannot use this solution because:
1. seems that I cannot use another structural directive like `*ngIf` on the same 
   checkbox
2. I want to avoid the need of another property like `showCustomIcon` in the 
   component where the checkbox is used. That would mean to add this property 
   to hundreds of components i am using `p-checkbox` in.

It would be better, if somehow i can deal with the issue completely in the logic of the directive and then all I want to do is adding this directive to all my checkboxes per find + replace.

You didn't mentionned any already existing structural directives, but then again, you could very well merge the *ngIf logic inside of this new structural directive, but attribute directives are not supposed to modify the DOM.

thank you for the advice. that does not fix my second point though: avoiding the need of showCustomIcon property. I would need to add that to each component that uses a p-checkbox

There might be a an exact solution to your problem but it's not gonna be easy, could you please share the version of Angular you're working with ?

sure, it is version 17.3.6.
it is the reason why we are here now. haha.
with the update come the changes I need to do now, because with angular 15 the way I used the custom icons for the checkboxes is not working anymore and I am trying to find an elegant solution with this post here, meaning, without touching all the code where the checkbox is used :)

I thought of wrapping the p-checkbox in an own component with all the @Input Properties that are used and the custom icon template defined there once. But it is not just @Output or @Input Properties that the primeng checkbox is shipped with that I need to make use of.
Additionally there are custom properties, in some cases needed in others not.
Hence, this would mean even if I create a Wrapper Checkbox Component and define the custom icon template there once, I would still need to change all the component HTMLs...

I think it would be easy just changing the tag <p-checkbox> to <wrapper-checkbox-comp> in all the HTMLs with RegEx and Find + Replace... but not with all that different variants with properties...
